# Relationship model of an inventory control

Tags: sql, relationship

I'm trying to create a mer diagram, for an inventory control with the following logic, I have 10 components of the same model (10 ACER 24 monitors, with the same characteristics.), The only thing that differentiates each of these components would be the serial number, so I had the following logic:

[image]

But I don't know if these relationships are correct, especially with the inventory part, would it be correct for me to add the serial number in the component entity, and create 10 inventory records?

[image]

I'm having a hard time choosing the best path for this logic that I described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In relational notation every relation must have a primary key, while in your example:

`stock`, `component_has_component_category`, `user_has_components` do not.

To solve it, add both fields in a primary key for each relation.

`components` relation on the other hand has a useless field `id`, which could be replaced with primary key `component_id` + `serial_number`, and so if a user has a component (refers by foreign key) relation `user_has_components` will have both fields `component_id` + `serial_number` which is logical, since the user has a specific component instance.

A hypothetical relation `components_inventory` would be similar, it has two fields `component_id` and `serial_number` which are both primary key and foreign key to `components`, denoting that a specific component with a serial number is present. (in some sense `components_inventory` is subset of `components`)

**EDIT**: My view of how it would look like data-wise:

```
component

| component_id | .. other stuff |
|            1 | ..             |
|            2 | ..             |


components (all existent components and serial numbers)

| component_id | serial_number |
|            1 |           101 |
|            1 |           102 |
|            1 |           103 |
|            1 |           104 |
|            2 |           201 |
|            2 |           202 |


user_has_component (refers to components)

| user_id | component_id | serial_number |
| mary    |            1 |           101 |
| john    |            1 |           104 |
| john    |            2 |           202 |

category_inventory (refers to components, some components we have, but not
users)

| component_id | serial_number | location           |
|            1 |           102 | warehouse New York |
|            1 |           103 | warehouse New York |
|            2 |           201 | warehouse Paris    |
```

Comment: I didn’t quite understand what you said about components_inventory, could you give me an example what fields would be in this table?

Comment: in case you talk to replace the name components with component_inventory

Comment: and in stock my primary key is my component id

Comment: `components_inventory` would have at least  `component_id` + `serial_number` primary key and it's at the same time a foreign key on `components`. It may have more fields for your needs (like a place of storing of a particular component)

Comment: Could you show me how the structure of this relationship would look in a table format?

Comment: I would be very grateful

Comment: Your're right about `component_id`, but nontheless your program doesn't show it

Comment: In this case I would have the following table:

component, components, component_inventory?

What would this component_inventory do?

Comment: I thought you need an `inventory` relation.

Comment: about components: component_id  + serial_number  are pk? And user_has_component : user_id  + component_id  + serial_number  are pk?

Comment: @Felipe yes, but in the latter case it's also fine to have rudimentary `id` pk since 3 and more fields in a PK/UK gives a big index, which might be bad for some real world applications

Comment: on this category_inventory ? or user_has_component?

Comment: user_has_component

Comment: can u help me bro ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62764976/entity-relationship-product-and-equipment